# Jest / Vue Test Utils - Axios mock works only in test file itself

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, mocking, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to create my first Vue.js 2.x tests and I could use some help:

For some reason, mocking only works on functions defined in the .spec file, but not on imported ones.

For example, the following code works:

```
// login.spec.js file - note "login" is defined here (which uses "axios" mock)

function login(email, password) {
    // I'm defined inside the spec file!
    let payload = { email, password };
    return axios.post(loginApiUrl, payload);
}

jest.mock('axios');

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
})
describe('Login.vue', () => {
    it('sample test', async () => {
        const data = { a: 1 };
        axios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce(data);
        let res = await login('abcd@example.com', 'password')
        expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        // The mock works!
```

While this doesn't:

```
// login.spec.js file
import auth from '@/api/auth.js'
jest.mock('axios');

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
})
describe('Login.vue', () => {
    it('sample test', async () => {
        const data = { a: 1 };
        axios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce(data);
        let res = await auth.login('abcd@example.com', 'password')
        expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        // This doesn't work (fetching the original URL)



// auth.js

import axios from 'axios'
import { loginApiUrl } from '../helpers/constants'

const auth = {
    login(email, password) {
        // params are string payloads login request
        // return: axios Promise
        let payload = { email, password };
        console.log('login')
        return axios.post(loginApiUrl, payload);
    }
}
export default auth;
```

Note that the second code makes a call to the actual URL (without the mock)

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code works for me (`axios.post` is properly mocked in my test run). Can you link to a reproduction?

Comment: It was a super helpful comment @tony19.
It helped me understand the issue is in the configuration, after a slight modification it works!

The problematic part is me importing the auth.login file in my jest.setup.js file.
Do you have an idea why it caused that unexpected behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with importing it in `jest.setup.js`? You might want to ask a new question with a reproduction. Also, feel free to post your own answer to this question below to help others that might encounter the same problem.

Comment: Alright, thanks :)